# Magento 2: Moving development installation to Live or not

Tags: magento2, upgrade, staging

We made a development copy of the Magento 2 site and we upgraded all the extensions and Magento 2 itself. Then we ran tests in order to make sure everything is working in development installation.

Do we have to do the same upgrade steps in the live production installation too or could we just copy the database from the production version to the development version and Magento would then handle upgrading database? Then we would just move the development version to be the new production version. Would this be the easiest way of handling system upgrade and would it work?

What would you recommend?

Comment: If your site was using composer its recommended you upgrade in that way. if you used the magento setup manager id recommend upgrading the website through that and any extensions under the app folder manually upgrade. i wouldnt recommend overwriteing the live database as you will lose valuable information the best course would be upgrade magento and then upgrade the extensions upon successful upgrade

Answer (score 0):

Basically you can do following steps:

a)Take production copy(db+files) and setup in your local.
   b)Then upgrade all extensions and fix errors/issues if any
   c)Now, replace upgraded db+files to production

NOTE: 
   Data captured(sales,customers data etc.) on production while step **b** has to move back to production after step **c** , in maintenance mode.

Reply back if you need more clarification